# Python save a variable on a file when KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python

Let me thanks in advance for the help

I want to know if someone can help me, when I press Ctrl+c I want that it open the file **keepline** and it overwrite what is there with **keeponline**(that it incremented on the main(). But I'm not being able to get the value from main() to the except, can someone please help me? Thanks once more

global keeponline

def main():

```
def signal_handler(signal, frame) :
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')

    print "Keeponline is", keeponline

    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

try:
    keepline = open("path", "r+")
    keeponline = keepline.readline()
    keeponline = int(keeponline)
    keepline.close()
except OSError:
    print "[*] File not found."

errorimg = "path"
lslinks = "path"

savepath = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/", title='Please select a directory')
if savepath == '':
    print "[*] The path to save can't be empty!"
    sys.exit()

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r"path")  #
driver.set_window_size(1600, 900)

count = 0
y = 1
z = 500
perfolder = 500
url = 'https://prnt.sc/'

def getfiles(count, keeponline, perfolder, y, z):
    with open('path', "r") as f:
        for i in xrange(keeponline):
            f.next()
        for line in f:
            keeponline += 1
            link = url + line
            driver.get(link)
            spage = driver.page_source  # save the page's html
            if errorimg in spage:
                print "Removed!"
                continue
            else:
                if count < 501:
                    if not os.path.exists(savepath + lslinks + ("(%s-%s)" % (y, z))):
                        os.makedirs(savepath + lslinks + ("(%s-%s)" % (y, z)))
                    driver.save_screenshot(
                        savepath + lslinks + ("(%s-%s)" % (y, z)) + "\\" + line[:-1] + ".png")
                    print "Saved!"
                    print keeponline
                    count += 1
                else:
                    y = y + perfolder
                    z = z + perfolder
                    count = 1
    keepline.close()
    f.close()
    driver.close()

while os.path.exists(savepath + lslinks + ("(%s-%s)" % (y, z))) == True:
    files = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir((savepath + lslinks + ("(%s-%s)" % (y, z)))), '*.txt'))
    if files < 500:
        count = files
        getfiles(count, keeponline, perfolder, y, z)
    else:
        y = y + perfolder
        z = z + perfolder
        if not os.path.exists(savepath + lslinks + ("(%s-%s)" % (y, z))):
            getfiles(count, keeponline, perfolder, y, z)
            break

if os.path.exists(savepath + lslinks + ("(%s-%s)" % (y, z))) == False:
    getfiles(count, keeponline, perfolder, y, z)
```

Comment: you are replacing the text in the variable `line` not in the ***actual line* in the text file**..

Comment: What do you mean with 'I'm not being able to get the value from main() to the except'?

Comment: This variable "keeponline" it's 0, but it's incremented 1 always that the for for cycle is running and on the main() it's like 9 but when the program it's going to end, it's 0 again

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It's not rigth the way I did it?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis correctly mentioned that you are not actually writing anything to the file. If you want to overwrite the previous file contents simple use `keepline.write(keeponline)` instead of the for-loop.

Comment: you cannot replace text in a file **in-place**. Open two files; the old one to read from and a new one to write to. Read lines from the old one and write them to the new one (with\without replacing them).

Comment: OP stated he simply wants to overwrite the current file contents with `keeponline`. I'm not sure why you would need to read the previous content first.

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys, but beside that error, the problem I'm asking help is that the variable "keeponline" is being 0 when it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I got exactly what you need,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
import time

global keeponline
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')

    print "Keeponline is", keeponline
    print "Saving the value"
    fd = open("output.txt","w+")
    fd.write(str(keeponline))
    fd.close()

    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

#Just an initilization
keeponline = 0

#Read a line in the file every second and increment the variable
fd = open("a.txt","r")

while True:
    line = fd.readline()
    keeponline += 1

    print "Line:", line
    time.sleep(2)

    #It is just an example condition
    if ( len(line) == 0 ):
        break

fd.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys, but beside that error, the problem I'm asking help is that the variable "keeponline" is being 0 when it shouldn't

Comment: Can you show us the full code? We don't know how you create keeponline

Comment: the keeponline it's just an incremented variable, for each line of the file that the program reads, he adds one to keeponline

Comment: I showed you the full code, I hope that it explain better than I did, if someone can help me

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Hi @ShwSvn, I tried to create a simple script that would recreate your case,. I hope this helps.

Comment: it helped me on one thing, but it don't save the value of the keeponline, if you can see it please http://prntscr.com/fz6sis
It should be 6 instead of 0

Comment: Hi, I have added few lines that would create a file with the content of keeponline. I hope that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alberto, but I have that and it's that part that is not working, when it writes on the files, it writes a 0 instead of the value of the variable

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I can't understand why. If you try the example code I put few days ago do you have the proper number saved. Just to make sure, I'd let you know that I updated it twice. Thanks

Comment: I will update the code, if you please can check that it's right with the code that you send

Comment: I updated the code, I'm not saving on a file because when he prints the value after Ctrl + c it is 0

Comment: Could you please check the code you pasted? It is not perfectly formatted. Thanks